# Is there a Dojo counterpart for the jQuery Timeago plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, dojo, timeago

Is this functionality provided by Dojo or Dijit?  A Dojo extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of, but this would be a useful feature (and something I need fairly soon anyway) so I created one.

I'll put it up on my github account at some point, but for now just find it at http://telliott.net/dojoExamples/timeago.zip.

I've not tested in IE, just Chrome and FF at the moment. LMK if you have any problems.

Tom

Comment: Cool! I would have created one myself, except that I had higher priority tasks to attend to. Will test this soon.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Tested, and it works great with some modifications: (1) I commented out the `define` enclosure (lines 9, 140-141), since I'm on Dojo 1.5; (2) fixed a typo in your `strings` settings for `hours`, where it said `"about $d hours"` when it should have been `"about %d hours"` (changed `$` to `%`).  Again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Haven't tested on IE yet, by the way.

Comment: Another modification:  line 60 says `'timeego_'`, changed it to `'timeago_'` (changed `e` to `a`)

Comment: Thanks Nikki - keep um coming! :)

Comment: I think this might be it on GitHub: https://github.com/michaloo/dojo-timeago

Comment: I never put this up. Ooops. Was waiting for dojo to land with AMD support and then rework it for that. They just released 1.8 so I guess I should get on and do that.